# How to find the parity check matrix for 101101101101101 in Hamming Codes (15,11) in graphic way?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, coding-theory

I am trying to find hamming matrix for safe coded word: 101101101101101

My questions are:

1) What matrix check I should use? I mean there are two types of 15,11 => one starting with 1111 and one starting with 0001 is that any difference?

2) How can I create it graphically? I dont know how to make matrix visible graphically for example in micosoft word what editor for it are you using to have it visible-friendly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are not just "two types" of 15,11 code: if your generator matrix has codewords in its rows then you can permute the columns however you like, and still have a 15,11 Hamming code. You won't be able to decode this without knowledge of what the generator matrix or associated parity check looks like.

Comment: I mean i Know of two types like this: http://ranger.uta.edu/~carroll/cse4317/reliability/sld053.htm and the "opposite" one starting column with 0001 - I know the basics and the system that I need to multiplay with that the number and find if it is non-zero number etc. but do not now which one to choose here. Also the second question would be nice :)